# Website Network, data collection

Tags: php

I am making a web development service which I am trying out at school.
The idea is to be able to run my CMS with a student's content.
I have made version 2 of the yet un-named CMS which allows the user to make a skin compatible with the CMS and easily use it. This part works fine.

The problem is, I said "We can collect site statistics for your website and notify you if there are any issues with your site." in a presentation, In which people seemed interested. What I need to do is be able to access information from the databases of all my client's sites from my administration domain hosted on another server. I could use a `file_get_contents();` on my admin site to retrieve a file on the client's site and echo's it. - Which I think is sloppy

Is there any other way, bearing in mind that my host does not allow database access from one site to another!

Thanks, especially for being able to read my overly long sentences!

Comment: what kind of issues? HTML/CSS errors, lack of visitors, illegal material ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
    function file_get_data($url) {
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
      //Set curl to return the data instead of printing it to the browser.
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      $data = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      return $data;
    }
```